# Run-time error 438 for excel script / mail merge word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, runtime-error, mailmerge

I get this error, VBA error run-time 438,  I just can't understand why, i'll briefly explain what I should do,

the excel file where this macro resides is a database where a word file (mod.docm) fetches the data with mail merge.

What I would like to obtain is a button inside the excel file that once clicked generates a pdf with the word model.

The script works flawlessly until the moment he has to select the exact record within the word file.

Can anyone give me some advice?

```
     Public Sub StampaUnione()
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim strFile As String
    
    
    Const wdExportFormatPDF As Integer = 17
    Const wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen As Integer = 1
    Const wdExportAllDocument As Integer = 0
    Const wdExportCreateNoBookmarks As Integer = 0
    
    strFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\File\mod.docm"
    
    
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(strFile)
        
    wordApp.Visible = True
    
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'recupero il numero matricola da stampa unione
    Var = Sheets("Foglio1").Range(ActiveCell.Address)
    
    'genero la directory dovve salvare il file
    cartellaMadre = "C:\Users\Desktop\File\" & Var & "\"
    
    'se la cartella non esiste la creo
    If Len(Dir(cartellaMadre, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
       MkDir cartellaMadre
    End If
    
    'genero la sotto cartella dove salvare il file
    cartellaFiglia = "C:\Users\File\" & Var & "\" & "Doc" & "\"
    
    'se la sotto cartella non esiste la creo
    If Len(Dir(cartellaFiglia, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
       MkDir cartellaFiglia
    End If
    
    'wordApp.Documents.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = False
    'wordApp.Documents.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord
    
    'If wordApp.Documents.MailMerge.DataSource.FindRecord(FindText:="020120", _
    'Field:="Matricola") = True Then
    'MsgBox "Data was found"
    'End If
    
 MsgBox "I'm Here - error"

        wordApp.Documents.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
        wordApp.Documents.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
            "C:\Users\Desktop\File\DB_StampaUnione.xlsm", _
            ConfirmConversions:=False, _
            ReadOnly:=False, _
            LinkToSource:=True, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            PasswordDocument:="", _
            PasswordTemplate:="", _
            WritePasswordDocument:="", _
            WritePasswordTemplate:="", _
            Revert:=False, _
            Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
            Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\Cristian\Desktop\File\DB_StampaUnione.xlsm;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Data", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Foglio1$` WHERE Matricola = '030120'", SQLStatement1:="", SubType:= _
            wdMergeSubTypeAccess
        wordApp.Documents.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = wdToggle
    
   
    
    'genero il PDF
        wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
            "C:\Users\File\" & Var & "\" & "Doc" & "\" & "D" & Var & ".pdf", _
            ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
            OpenAfterExport:=False, _
            OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, _
            Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
            From:=1, _
            To:=1, _
            Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
            IncludeDocProps:=True, _
            KeepIRM:=True, _
            CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
            DocStructureTags:=False, _
            BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
            UseISO19005_1:=True
           
        wordDoc.Close 'chiude file di word
        wordApp.Quit 'chiude word
    
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
     Set wordApp = Nothing
     Set wordDoc = Nothing
    
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: Don't know if that's your problem, but your filename pathes look strange: I doubt that you have a folder `C:\Users\Desktop` or `C:\Users\File`

Comment: yes I know, I changed them in a strange way because they contained sensitive data

Comment: Advice: you should **(a)** use `Option Explicit` and **(b)** add a reference to the "Microsoft Word Object Library" and change your code to early binding.

Comment: Microsoft Word Object Library is already added, i have inserted the Option Explicit but i receive the same error "object doesn't support property or method"

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments, you have already added a reference to the Word Object Library. Change your code to early binding, this will reveal problems like that at compile time:

```
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
(...)
wordApp.Documents.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
```

This will throw a compiler error: *"Method or Data member not found"*. The compiler highlights "MailMerge", that means the `Documents`-property of the Word application has no such member.

When thinking about that, the reason is quite obvious: The `Documents`-property is a list of all open word documents. What you mean is the `MailMerge`-property of a single document:

```
wordApp.Documents(1).MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
```

However, don't use this. You already have a reference to the document (stored in variable  `wordDoc`), so use that:

```
wordDoc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
```

Comment: `code`wordDoc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters `code` Now error 4605 run-time error

Comment: That's a complete different question. Sorry, I cannot help you out with that - I don't know much about mail merge. If you investigate but cannot figure out, raise a new question "Why do I get runtime error 4605"